# Is there a tool in Linux for opening 3D files like STL and GLB?

Tags: ubuntu, 3d

I generated an STL file using OpenSCAD, but I'm unable to view it because I don't have any software that can open it. Are there any free and open-source software packages that can view STL files and can be installed on Ubuntu using the command `sudo apt-get install <packagename>`?

Comment: If you are unable to locate a program which provides your specific requirements, STL files can be viewed via an online STL viewer, which can be found by searching for those terms. I used also "ubuntu stl viewer" and found a single command line program, but no link for download, hence no answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can install Blender using `sudo apt-get install blender` and it can [import STL files](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/import_export/stl.html).

Answer (score 2):

[FreeCAD](https://www.freecad.org) can [import STL files](https://wiki.freecad.org/Import_from_STL_or_OBJ) for viewing an editing. You can install it with the command:

```
sudo apt install freecad
```